# Not sure how to infinite loop this

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I'm scratching my head on how I would do this last check after the 5-minute pause to see if I have regenerated enough Health to continue or not. I'll post the current loop below:

the order it should execute is as follows: Starts hunting without issue > It knows how much Health it currently has > When below 8000 health it will pause for 5 minutes as attended > But will not check to see if above 8000 health to continue after the pause > if not above it should keep waiting.

```
while health >= 8000:
health = letBattle()
if health <= 8000:
    driver.get("https://s3-en.bitefight.gameforge.com:443/profile/index") 
    print("////// RESTING FOR 5 MINUTES TO RECOVER! //////")
    time.sleep(300)
    #ADD HEALTH CHECK
    driver.get("https://s3-en.bitefight.gameforge.com:443/profile/index") #Refresh HP
else:
    print("------FINDING NEW PREY!------")
```

Under #ADD HEALTH CHECK is where I then refresh the browser to view the new updated health... but it just ends and doesn't loop. While above 8000 health it knows to keep hunting over and over again which is great... But when it triggers the pause when below 8000 health, it does nothing and it completely stops instead of continuing to wait until it's above 8000 health again to keep running infinitely.

Thanks in advance for the help/insight into my issue

Comment: It's difficult to know the details of the code given what you have posted, but have you tried using `while health <= 8000:` instead of `if health <= 8000:`?

Comment: I will edit and post the full code. I'm not sure if changing that specifically would help

Comment: Surely you need to actually *capture the result* of `driver.get` and re-parse the output?

Answer (score 2):

it should be something like this:

```
while True:
    health = # getting health value
    if health >= 800:
        # do something
    else:
        sleep(300)
```